# Non-Alphabetical Index for UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How does one implement a NON alphabetical index for a UITableView?  An example of this can be seen in Apple's Remote App.  When looking at songs, there is a dotted index on the right hand side that allows the user to scroll quickly through the entire table.  There are also no section headers.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that it works by returning an array full of the “middle dot” character (Unicode 00B7), bookended by the “bullet” character (2022). In the Remote app, the index has 23 items in it; therefore, to do this, you need to split up your data into 23 sections of roughly equal length. As occulus says, returning `nil` or `@""` in `-tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` will cause no section headers to be shown.

Return the aforementioned array of characters in your data source’s `-sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` method, then implement `-tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:` to return the section index it gives you, and you should get identical behavior to Remote’s.

Comment: Noah, thanks.  Looking into it a bit more, I think it's a little bit more complicated.  It looks the Apple Remote is dividing songs into chunks of 34 (at least for me, with ~11000 songs).  So while it shows 23 index markers on the right, it is creating significantly more.  I wonder if it is just doing all the math on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

If you specify `@""` for a section title, the section header won't be shown, which will give you the effect you desire. To use table indexing (the right hand side tiny list), you should still organise your table in sections so it knows where to jump when a index is touched, you just have to hide the section titles as I described.

To add index items, see UITableViewDelegate's method:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

Comment: Thanks.  How does Apple achieve the bulleted index list seen in the Remote? Is there an index "style" for this, or are they just making an array of bullets?